# Including custom code block in a child document with bookdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

I am trying to include custom blocks in a child .Rmd document in bookdown, however custom blocks included in the child document are not compiled.

I've followed the instructions for using custom blocks here https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/custom-blocks.html

I loaded a new template bookdown project. If I insert a custom block in a chapter, such as `01-intro.Rmd`, then the custom block works as expected. For example, including

````
```{block, type="center"}
hello world
```
````

produces the expected html output on build book:

```
<div class="center">
<p>
hello
</p>
</div>
```

And, the expected tex output:

```
\begin{center}
hello
\end{center}
```

However, the expected outputs do not occur if the custom code block is included in a child document. For example, I created a new .Rmd file `testchild.Rmd` that contains:

````
```{block, type="center"}
hello world
```
````

And, I include the child document in the chapter document `01-intro.Rmd` as follows:

````
 ```{r child="childfolder/testchild.Rmd", echo=FALSE}
 ```
````

Now, building the book fails to include the custom block from `testchild.Rmd`. Specifically, nothing regarding the custom block is written to html or latex. Any other text and other knitr chunks in `testchild.Rmd` are included without a problem.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Found one workaround, which is to print the child to the parent. Including the following in the parent document `01-intro.Rmd`, instead of the above method of including the child document seems to allow the custom blocks in the child to be compiled correctly.

````
 ```{r, echo=FALSE}
 knitr::asis_output(knitr::knit_child("childdoc/testchild.Rmd", quiet=TRUE))
 ```
````